# Setting up mail server with Zoho & making own phpMail function for it

Tags: php, email, smtp

I don't know if my code is the issue or if I had configured Zoho's SMTP's settings incorrectly.

Basically I want the ability to dynamically send emails with a simple php function like for example

```
phpMail("to@example.com", $subject, $body, "from@example.com", "replyto@example.com");
```

This is my PHPMailer.php script (it sees the function and its settings)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '**REMOVED**';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '**REMOVED**';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML


// SYTAX: phpMail($from, $reply, $to, $subject, $body);
function phpMail($to, $subject, $body, $from = "from@example.com", $reply = "replyto@example.com") {
    if (isset($from)) 
        $mail->From = $from;
        $mail->FromName = "testing";

    if (isset($to)) 
        $mail->addAddress($to);

    if (isset($reply)) 
        $mail->addReplyTo($reply);

    if (isset($subject)) 
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

    if (isset($body)) 
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = $body;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }

}
```

Now the issue with this is that, I'm not receiving emails nor am I receiving any errors / messages but it's also not sending me an email.

Comment: You have not passed the `$mail` object as a parameter to your `phpMail()` function. So as it will be out of scope, it must be erroring. Check your php error log. or better still test with these 2 lines at the top of your PHP code `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: `require('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');` Are you referring to this?

Comment: No, you have wriiten a function that uses the `$mail` object, but you instantiate that object outside the function, therefore it will not _by default_ be visible inside the function **see scope** So either pass the object as a parameter to the function or instantiate the object inside the function

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a PHP function, make sure your objects aren't outside of your function.

My error wasn't that though, it was basically my own stupidity which had nothing to do with the code but more of my "form post data".

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works for me using zoho mail.
Give it a try:

```
$mail=new JPhpMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host='smtp.zoho.com';
// Enable this option to see deep debug info
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port='465';
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;

$mail->Username='your_email_address';
$mail->Password='your_eamil_address_password';

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->SetFrom('your_email_address','Your Name');

$mail->Subject='PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication';
$mail->AltBody='To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->MsgHTML('<h1>JUST A TEST!</h1>');

$mail->AddAddress('destination_email_address','John Doe');

 if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Are the mail->username and mail->password your zoho email username and password? Also, did you install smpt on your server before running this script?

Comment: yes, also you must use the from email, within the email itself the same you use in the smtp authentication. Otherwise the smtp send might not work.